# How to remove/hide matplotlib slider values

Tags: python, widget, matplotlib

I have a simple slider using matplotlib slider widget.  Now by default on the right hand side of the slider it shows the current value of the slider.  However I would like to remove or hide this value from being displayed.  Is it possible to do so and if so how?
Here is an illustration of what I currently have (the top image shows the slider with the current value) and what I want (the bottom image shows the slider but without the slider value being displayed).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Slider.valtext` is the text object, you can toggle it by:

```
sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=f0)
sfreq.valtext.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Where is this documented?  I can't find anything about this valtext member variable